# Practice extracting variables

Tags: php

Is better to use `$id_name ( Class A Method b() )` OR `$id_name_2 ( Class A Method c())`?

```
<?php

Class A { 

    function a(){
        $params = array(
            'id'=> 1,
            'name' => 'b',
        );

        $id_name = $this->b($params);
        $id_name_2 = $this->c($params);
    }

    function b($params){
        $id = $params['id'];
        $name = $params['name'];
        /*******

            Some code performing operations with $name and $id

        ********/

        $str = $id . $name; 
        return $str;
    }


    function c($params){

        /*******

            Some code performing operations with $params['name'] and $params['id']

        ********/

        $str = $params['name'] . $params['id'];

        return $str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `$params` being used at all inside of the "Code Performing Operations?" If not, both methods are nearly identical.

Answer (score 1):

Using method `c` will have an side-effect if `$params` is modified. This is because arrays are passed by reference, and so any changes to `$params` will be visible to the caller when the function returns. Use `b` if you need to manipulate id or name, unless you intend to return the modifications to the caller.

Example:

```
$params = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'b');
$this->d($params);
echo $params['id']; // outputs 2
...

function d($params) {
    $params['id']++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using method B.  It will make for more readable code and will lead to less mystery bugs.

One cool PHP trick for extracting an assosiative array into variables is the [Extract](http://www.php.net/extract) method.

```
$params = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'foo'
);

extract($params);

echo $name . $id;
//"Foo1"
```

This makes more sense when you've got more elements, but I've always found it to be a clean way to express what you're trying to do.

The reverse is [Compact](http://www.php.net/compact) which is great if you need to convert your values back to their original array form.

Comment: My experience is that using `extract` can be a bit dangerous unless you are really sure of what you are doing and what the contents of the array are. Consider the fact that the old register_globals setting were doing an extract of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and others... and register_globals was one of the most horrible security leaks of PHP ever.

Comment: I'm always sure what I'm doing ;)  But you are definitely correct.  I've always used extract on some kind of data model I wanted to operate on that had tons of properties.  The arrays themselves were returned through class methods that I either wrote or thoroughly understood, so the safety was there.  If you don't have this consistency with your input arrays, it will be safer to just assign them manually.